# Multiple vars assignment in one sentence in PHP

Tags: php

I am asking what could be the consequences of this var assignment definition:

```
$component = $id = $class = '';
```

I mean is allowed by the IDE (phpStorm), the code doesn't return any warnings, fatal or anything else but .... there is any but?

What do you think?

Comment: it's fine. that is standard syntax.

Comment: I personally don't see anything wrong with it in PHP. Just be aware that this type of assignment might work differently in other languages. In javascript, I believe, this will create three variables pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is okay.

PHP uses a copy on write system. It means that with primitive types such as strings or ints are really created in memory on change and will probably be okay in your example.

**php**

```
$component = $id = $class = 'foobar';

var_dump($component);
var_dump($id);
var_dump($class);
```

**output**

```
string 'foobar' (length=6)
string 'foobar' (length=6)
string 'foobar' (length=6)
```

But be careful when you do this with objects, objects are passed by reference and have different behavior:

**PHP**

```
class Obj
{
    public $_name;
}

$a = $b = new Obj();
$component = $id = $class = 'foobar';

$b->_name = 'Reynier'; //try to change name of second object only
$id = 'Reynier'; // try to change $id only

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);

var_dump($component);
var_dump($id);
var_dump($class);
```

**output**

```
#Both object are changed
object(Obj)[1]
  public '_name' => string 'Reynier' (length=7)
object(Obj)[1]
  public '_name' => string 'Reynier' (length=7)

#only $id was changed
string 'foobar' (length=6)
string 'Reynier' (length=6)
string 'foobar' (length=6)
```