# How to define multiple variables with different values at once in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I initialize multiple PHP variables with different values in a single line? I wish to write a single line code that is equivalent to the following:

```
 $v1='value1';
 $v2=2;
 $v3='value3';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple vars assignment in one sentence in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976217/multiple-vars-assignment-in-one-sentence-in-php)

Comment: NooO!!  How it could be my answer?  I want to define different values to the variables, on the other hand, the given answer for identical value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find a solution when I was debugging the laravel db-query package I noticed the solution. We can achieve this by following the below syntax.

```
[$v1, $v2, $v3] = ['vale1', 2, 'value2'];

var_dump($v2);
```